# Powershell script is not appending .CSV

Tags: powershell, append, export-csv

I am trying to automatize generating reports that we have to do daily on the DB but I first need the generator its self work accordingly so I can create a schedule task for it.

So I wrote a script that should fetch data from DB and export it to CSV but the problem is that it wont append and stops exporting at first sql.

```
$serverName = $Global:setupConfiguration["GENERAL SETTINGS"]["ODBC_DATASOURCE_NAME"]
$databaseName = $Global:setupConfiguration["CASINO CONFIGURATION"]["DATABASENAME"]
$recordSetToFileName = @{0='1.csv';}
$currentRecordSetIndex = -1
$progAccount = $null
$iniBaseSection = $false
#Execute the SQL on the local database and dumps a csv in C:/Automation/

#fetches the data to temp table
$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\0.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv $fileName -notypeinformation -force -Encoding utf8

#selects from temp table and exports.

$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\1.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv  $fileName -notypeinformation  -Encoding utf8 -Force


$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\2.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv -Append -Path $fileName -notypeinformation  -Encoding utf8 -Force

$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\3.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv  -Append -Path $fileName -notypeinformation  -Encoding utf8 -Force

$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\4.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv -Append -Path $fileName -notypeinformation  -Encoding utf8 -Force

$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\5.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv -Append -Path $fileName -notypeinformation -Encoding utf8 -Force

$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\6.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv -Append -Path $fileName -notypeinformation -Encoding utf8 -Force

$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\7.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv -Append -Path $fileName -notypeinformation -Encoding utf8 -Force

$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\8.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv -Append -Path $fileName -notypeinformation -Encoding utf8 -Force

$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\9.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv -Append -Path $fileName -notypeinformation -Encoding utf8 -Force

$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\10.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv -Append -Path $fileName -notypeinformation -Encoding utf8 -Force

$sqlFile = "$($Global:globalVariables.executionPath)\sql\11.sql"
$data = Invoke-SqlQuery -File $sqlFile -Server $serverName -Database $databaseName
$fileName = "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\$($recordSetToFileName[0])"
$data | export-csv -Append -Path $fileName -notypeinformation -Encoding utf8 -Force
```

Comment: you are referring to the saved CSV file with `$($recordSetToFileName[0]` and that will always be `1.csv` since you never change it. are you SURE the other sections are not running ... because it looks like you are simply overwriting the output file every time.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey , it shouldnt overwrite as I am using -append and i am using $($recordSetToFileName[0] for naming as some reports required different reports .csv files but this one doesnt require it.

Comment: not sure why it "stops" since you don't give us much information. Sounds like the other statements are not even running? does `$data` even have anything returned in subsequent scripts? Is it silently failing? PLEASE make a function for this. You have the code repeated over and over. right now its a pain to make a change to `$filename`

Comment: your 1st & 2nd exports don't use `-Append`. i managed to miss that the _others_ do use that parameter. you likely otta add that to the 2nd one. [*grin*]

Comment: 1st one should even have output as it's what creates a temporary table in DB and first one as 2nd is the first one that creates the 1.csv file and anything else should just append to it and thats where it fails. as for $filename, it should matter as I am just appending to previous.

Comment: `$fileName` appears fine. However we cannot tell if `$data` contains anything useful in later calls. If it is null then the CSV would not show it. Perhaps debug to check if there are even values to write to file first? Also... do these queries even return the same column set?

Comment: @Matt , I have tested each $data and each one prints correctly and even when I run SQL Profiler on the DB. The queries are going through. The issue here is that it wont amend. It first creates 1.csv and prints into it 1st query and then wont ammend any following queries.

Comment: Are they returning the _exact same_ columns?

Comment: They are returning correct DATA as I have other script that returns the data but on different server but I need this script to work as I want it to store dumps locally and them via STMP Automatically send to Customer so the issue is not what they are printing as everything is printing correctly, the issue here is that it wont amend and rewrites 1.csv

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? `-Append` wasn't added to `Export-Csv` till v3.

Comment: @BenjaminHubbard , PS Version 5.1.14409

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution and I just merged the .CSV

```
#Merges ALL .CSV Files to final.CSV

$getFirstLine = $true

get-childItem "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\CSVTemp\*.csv" | foreach {
    $filePath = $_

    $lines =  $lines = Get-Content $filePath  
    $linesToWrite = switch($getFirstLine) {
           $true  {$lines}
           $false {$lines | Select -Skip 1}

    }

    $getFirstLine = $true
    Add-Content "$($Global:globalVariables.localDirectory)\CSVTemp\$nameFinal" $linesToWrite
    }
```